# named Piped C issue

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I have this C code:

```
   #define BUFSIZE 256
    int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int fdIn;
        int fdOut;


        if( argc != 3)
        {
            perror("Error argument");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Input Pipe\n");
        if( (fdIn = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY ) )<0)
        {
            perror("Error opening input pipe");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Output Pipe\n");
        if( (fdOut = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY ) )<0)
        {
            perror("Error opening output pipe");
            exit(1);
        }

        int c = 2;
        printf("Start cicle\n");
        while(c--)
        {
            char var1[BUFSIZE];
            char var2[BUFSIZE];
            char string[100];

            memset(var1, 0, sizeof(var1));
            memset(var2, 0, sizeof(var2));
            memset(string, 0, sizeof(string));


            if( readLine(fdIn, var1, sizeof(var1)) == 0)
            {
                printf("exit \n");
                exit(0);
            }

            if( readLine(fdIn, var2, sizeof(var2)) == 0)
            {
                printf("exit \n");
                exit(0);
            }



            if( atoi(var2) != 0){
                if( atoi(var1) == 0  || (atoi(var1) % atoi(var2)) == 0 )
                    sprintf(string,"ok\n");
                else
                    sprintf(string,"no\n");

            }

            printf("%s", string);
            writeLine(fdOut, string, strlen(string));
        }
        close(fdOut);
        close(fdIn);
        exit(0);
    }
```

Functions in the code:

```
int readLine( int fd, char* str, int bufferSize)
{
    return readToDel(fd, '\n', str, bufferSize);
}

int readToDel( int fd, char delimiter, char* str, int bufferSize)
{
    int n;
    int byteLetti =0;
    int index=0;


    do /* Read characters until NULL or end-of-input */
    {

        if( (n = read (fd, str+index, 1)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Error descriptor\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        byteLetti+=n;


    }
    while (n > 0 && *(str+index++) != delimiter && index < bufferSize);


    return byteLetti; /* Return false if end-of-input */
}
int writeLine(int fd, char* buffer, int bufferSize)
{
    if( write (fd, buffer, bufferSize) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

My problem is How use these pipes , I'll explain:

I have 2 pipes by input( the input's program is the 2 absolute pipes' path), one of this pipe is of Input and other is output. 
In the input pipes there are some data ( in particular two numbers) and , after elaboration, I have to write "ok" or "no" in the output pipe.
For this reason , by terminal , I did  `echo "4\n2\n" > input` so I write in the input's pipe the two numbers.
Then I execute the program in this way:

```
./program inputPipeAbsolutePath outputPipeAbsolutePath
```

but the program is blocking on the line  `printf("Output Pipe\n");` before third if statement from start and I don't know why.
What wrong?

I tested it on Mac

UPDATE 
no one can help me?

Comment: I think you're confusing pipes and streams...

Comment: can you explain me what do I wrong please? i'm new in pipes

Comment: Using perror for arguments is likely to lead to error messages like: "Error argument: Success" or "Error argument: is not a typewriter".  Just use fprintf (or fputs) when you don't care about the value of errno.

Comment: Are you reading from the pipe? I suspect it is not blocking on the printf, but on the open.  Did you run this in gdb and see it make it past the open, or are you assuming it is blocking on the printf because you see no output?  Until there is a reader, the open will not complete.

Comment: I agree with @WilliamPursell.  You're not blocking on the printf unless you're writing to the pipe and there's no readers -  but I can't be sure of it.   The code you pasted doesn't compile for me.  How are you building this?  I really need a working example if I'm to try to help you troubleshoot.  Can you please show all contents of files as well as the commands you're using to build and execute?

Comment: yes the program compiles. Yes it blocks on open. how do I resolve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand How do I test this program. Before running this program , I run by the terminal to write something in the pipe input this command : "echo "4\n2\n" > input". When I execute this program i'd like to open the input pipe for reading it's content , then open the output pipe and write in it something after elaboration , but the program blocks on the opening of the output pipe and I do not know how to behave.

Answer (score 0):

> the program blocks on the opening of the output pipe and I do not know
>   how to behave.

The program behaves as documented; see [`man fifo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html):

```
       Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.
```

So, one option for you is to start a program (e. g. `cat`) that reads from your *output pipe*; your program will then proceed.
The other option is to use O_RDWR instead of O_WRONLY:

```
       Under Linux, opening a FIFO for read and write will succeed both in
       blocking and nonblocking mode.  POSIX leaves this behavior undefined.
       This can be used to open a FIFO for writing while there are no
       readers available.
```